# How to pass multiple values in RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, postman

How to pass multiple values in RequestParam and retrieve them.

```
public List<String> get(@RequestParam("query") String query)

query = [a | b | c].
```

Where a, b, and c are optional.
How can we pass the query as a param. When a&c are optional and if we pass ",b,".
Then I am getting array as[" ", b] after splitting with ",". Instead of [" ", b, " "].

How can I pass the query as a param, so that I can get an array of three strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need distinct List params, each one named after the query param.

given
i.e

```
request: /your-resource?param1=1,2,3&param2=4,5&param3=10

@Controller

@RequestMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> foo(@RequestParam("params1") List<String> param1, @RequestParam("param2") List<String> params2, @RequestParam("param3") List<String> params3 )
```

Would result in 1,2,3 injected into param1. 4,5 into param2 and 10 into param3.